# Push doesn't disappear after clicking

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an issue with push notifications in iOS 7. When I click on push in notification panel, it will redirect me to my app, but push doesn't disappear in notification panel. I can click it again and again. How can I fix this issue? Is it a problem on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

This will clear the notification!

Comment: if its help then can you accept so that it wont queue into unanswered